# Rust: either 'cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time' or 'lifetime may not live long enough'

Tags: rust, lifetime

When calling App.create() in the below code, I either get one error or the other, depending on whether or not I add a lifetime to the second function. I don't understand what's happening with lifetimes enough to resolve.

Without the extra 'b lifetime on create_new_pop_in_chain the error is: '

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/genepool/types.rs:204:9
    |
107 | impl<'b> App<'b> {
    |      -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
188 |         pub fn create_new_pop_in_chain(&mut self,
    |                                        - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
204 |         self.chains.chains.get_mut(&chain_id).unwrap().pops.push((self.next_pop_id - 1, pref));
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'b`
```

With the lifetime, I get:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/genepool/types.rs:180:13
    |
107 | impl<'b> App<'b> {
    |      -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
180 |             self.create_new_pop_in_chain(1);
    |             ^^^^---------------------------
    |             |
    |             `*self` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
    |             argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'b`
```

Code in question. I've cut a lot of stuff out, trying to leave the important stuff, but can add any other context required.

```
pub struct App<'a> {
    pub chains: Chains<'a>,
    populations: HashMap<PopID, Population>,
    <snip>
}

pub struct Population {
    next_id: CellID,
    pop: HashMap<CellID, Cell>
}

impl<'b> App<'b> {

    pub fn create(&'b mut self, n: i32) {
        for _ in 0..n {
            // let chain_id = self.chains.new_chain();
            self.create_new_pop_in_chain(1);
        }
    }

    // Adding lifetime of 'b to make this &'b mut self, causes the alternate error
    pub fn create_new_pop_in_chain(&mut self, chain_id: ChainID) {
        let pref: &Population = self.populations.get(&self.next_pop_id).unwrap();
        self.chains.chains.get_mut(&chain_id).unwrap().pops.push((self.next_pop_id - 1, pref));        
    }
}

pub struct Chain<'a> {
    pub data: i32,
    pub pops: Vec<(PopID, &'a Population)>
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Chains<'c> {
    next_chain_id: usize,
    pub chains: HashMap<ChainID, Chain<'c>>,
}
```

TIA for any help!

Comment: `&'b mut self` where `'b` appears in `Self` is (almost?) always wrong.

Comment: Let me guess: you tried to create a self-referential struct.

Comment: What's in the `<snip>`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah I don't really understand what specifying lifetime on self even means.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's not self referential recursively or circularly as far as I know. The &Population that I want to store in chain.pops _is_ created and stored in another part of the App struct though. Should I be looking for circular references to resolve this?

Comment: This is _exactly_ self referential.

Comment: Have added in only other relevant stuff from the snip which is where the Population instances are stored.

Comment: Some possible solutions: (1) store only the key to the hashmap, (2) store `Rc<Population>` (or `Arc`) both in the map and in the reference (have you considered what happens when the map grows?)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The root of this issue is that I want refs to Population rather than ID's that need looking up later. No, haven't considered what happens when this map grows. App.populations needs to hold 1-100 million items.

Comment: When the map grows, it allocates in a new location, and all previous references to its items are invalidated. If you access them you have a use-after-free. Rust has actually saved you here.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah! Didn't consider that things would move around with resizing, etc. and holding refs to their memory locations over those events would therefore obviously become invalid! Thanks for that explanation